# How to find duplicates in a List<T> quickly, and update the original collection

Tags: linq, generics, sorting

Let me start by saying I've read these questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223400/checking-for-duplicates-in-a-complex-object-using-linq-or-lamda-expression) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454601/how-to-count-duplicates-in-list-with-linq), and I understand that I can write the code to find duplicates in my List, but my problem is I want to update the original list not just query and print the duplicates.

I know I can't update the collection the query returns as it's not a view, it's an anonymous type `IEnumerable<T>`.

I want to be able to find duplicates in my list, and mark a property I've created called `State` which is used later in the application.

Has anyone ran into this problem and can you point me in the right direction?

p.s.  The approach I'm using ATM is a bubble sort type loop to go through the list item by item and compare key fields.  Obviously this isn't the fastest method.

EDIT:

In order to consider an item in the list a "duplicate", there are three fields which must match.  We'll call them Field1, Field2, and Field3

I have an overloaded Equals() method on the base class which compares these fields.

The only time I skip an object in my `MarkDuplicates()` method is if the objects state is `UNKNOWN` or `ERROR`, otherwise, I test it.

Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks again!

Comment: please don't use BubbleSort,...ever!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to start by writing an extension method which find's duplicates in a list of objects.  Since you're objects use .Equals() they can be compared in most common collections.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
  var hashset = new HashSet<T>();
  foreach ( var cur in enumerable ) { 
    if ( !hashset.Add(cur) ) {
      yield return cur;
    }
  }
}
```

Now it should be pretty easy to update your collection for duplicates.  For instance

```
List<SomeType> list = GetTheList();
list
  .FindDuplicates()
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(x => x.State = "DUPLICATE");
```

If you already have a ForEach extentsion method defined in your code, you can avoid the .ToList.

Answer (score 1):

Your objects have some sort of state property. You're presumably finding duplicates based on another property or set of properties. Why not:

```
List<obj> keys = new List<object>();

foreach (MyObject obj in myList)
{
    if (keys.Contains(obj.keyProperty))
        obj.state = "something indicating a duplicate here";
    else
        keys.add(obj.keyProperty)
}
```

Comment: This, except that if you have a lot of objects you should use a HashSet for "keys" instead of a List.

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<T> oldList;
IEnumerable<T> list;

foreach (var n in oldList.Intersect(list))
   n.State = "Duplicate";
```

Edit: I need to lrn2read. this code is for 2 lists. My bad.